# Read property value directly on the class ( using this )

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have class like this: ( I simplify the class in order to explain)

```
public class CRecherche
{

    bool m_TestA;
    bool m_TestB;
    bool m_TestC;

    public CRecherche()
    {

    }

    public myFonction()
    { 
        bool bValue = (bool)typeof(CRecherche).GetProperty("m_Test"+"A").GetValue(this,null);
    }
}
```

I would like to read the m_TestA, m_TestB, and m_TestC using the name.

I have tried :

```
(bool)typeof(CRecherche).GetProperty("m_Test"+"A").GetValue(this,null);
```

But there is no succes.

Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this over simply accessing the private variable directly? In addition, your current code won't compile. Your `myFonction` method has no return type, nor does it contain a `return` statement.

Comment: @Cory is asking why `bool bValue = m_TestA;` is no good.

Comment: It's just in order to explain ! In my real class i have a good return type,etc... I just want to read my property by name because i will make comparaison with a tabArray. Why I have an nullReference Exception on : 
        bool bValue = (bool)typeof(CRecherche).GetProperty("m_Test"+"A").GetValue(this,null);

Comment: Sure, but why all the reflection? Why `.GetProperty` and all that?

Comment: Could you give me an example please ?

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni: You get a `NullReferenceException` because `typeof(CRecherche).GetProperty("m_Test"+"A")` is `null`. You don't have any *properties* in your class, only *fields*. You're using the wrong method to look for `m_TestA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on here that are working against you. First, your variables `m_TestA`, etc. aren't *properties*, they are fields. So instead of using `GetProperty()`, you should try `GetField()`:

```
return (bool)typeof(CRecherche)
    .GetField("m_TestA", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(this);
```

The second is that they have *private* visibility by default, so you have to help out the reflector by asking it to look for non-public and instance fields, as I have done above.